# How can I claim British citizenship for my child while we live in India?

Tags: uk-citizens

My unborn child's father is a British citizen. We are expecting our baby end of January 2018. I am in India and the father is in UK. We are not married yet as he is financially very unstable and is redundant right now. I have a very stable job here in India and we would like to wait for the time when he's financially more stable and I could risk leaving my job here in India.

I would like to apply for a British citizenship for my child so that I will not need to apply for a visa for them when I travel to the UK to see their daddy and grandparents. I am very much in touch with the father and his family.

Is it possible to obtain British citizenship for my child as the father is British?

Comment: Are you an Indian citizen? If so, the child will be an Indian citizen at birth (in addition to British citizen if applicable), but will lose that Indian citizenship if the child gets a foreign passport.

Comment: I am an Indian living in India and the father of my unborn child is British. We are not married. I visit UK every now and then to spend time with him. Our child will be born in India that disqualify them from being a UK citizen automatically. I would like to apply for a passport that will give them the right to travel to the UK without any restrictions and  live in India with me by obtaining OCI and it is their right as their father is a British and lives there. So do I still have to go to the UK to apply for their passport or can it be done here in India.

Comment: Is the father a British citizen "by descent" (i.e. they were born outside the UK and got British citizenship at birth from parents), or "otherwise than by descent" (any other way, e.g. if they were born in the UK or naturalized in the UK)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can/will provide any and all necessary evidence to demonstrate that he is the father and that the father is British otherwise than by descent, then the child was born a British Citizen (in the eyes of the UK government). You can apply for a British passport directly for the child or an ROA in an Indian passort for the child if you wish. As noted in the comments, once the child exercises British citizenship (such as by applying for a passport) they will lose Indian citizenship.